# Parsing this JSON in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I tried quite a lot but I am unable to parse this JSON in android.

could someone help?

```
[ 
  "m", 
  ["mapquest", "maps", "msn"],
  ["", "", ""],
  [], 
  {
    "type": ["KEY", "KEY", "KEY"],
    "PAIR": [1, 2, 3],
    "COUNT": 3
  }
]
```

This is my code.

```
JSONArray result = new JSONArray(res);

if (result.length() > 0){
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); ++i)
{
//it errors here....
JSONObject menuObject = result.getJSONObject(i);
}
}
```

Comment: is this the format of the JSON at all times? or you don't know from before hand which one is an array and which one is not?

Comment: This is not a standard JSON format.

Comment: @PareshMayani i took it back cause its valid JSON.We cannot say the compiler would throw an error reading such JSON,although it is not `standard`

Comment: @Nezam Where I said compiler will throw exception or error? I just said its not standard, that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to parse current json string as:

```
JSONArray result = new JSONArray(res);

if (result.length() > 0){
 for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); ++i)
 {
  Object obj = result.get(i);
  if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
     JsonArray jsonarr = (JSONArray)obj;
    for (int j = 0; j < jsonarr.length();j++)
      String str_one=jsonarr.optString(j);
     }
   }else{
      JSONObject jsonobj = (JSONObject)obj;
      JsonArray jsonarr_type =jsonobj.getJSONArray("type");
      for (int j = 0; j < jsonarr_type.length();j++)
         String str_typejsonarr_type.optString(j);
      }
      /// do same for PAIR 
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: You should include some detail about code otherwise he/she never came to what mistake he did in code.

Comment: actually the question itself was vague.Technically, `error` is a very unclear way to define your issue.Unless you support it with `Logcat` dump or give us an insight into what `Exception` was thrown.It is not possible that people would guess your problem.

Answer (score 0):

That JSON contains both arrays and objects. You can use the `opt` methods to check what the type is. If `optJSONObject` returns Null, then it's an array.

```
JSONArray result = new JSONArray(res);

if (result.length() > 0){
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); ++i)
{
    JSONObject menuObject = result.optJSONObject(i);
    if(menuObject == null)
    {
        JSONArray arr = result.optJSONArray(i);
        // process the array
    }
    else
    {
       // process the object
    }
}
```